# Is is possible to use < or > in prepared stements

Tags: php, mysqli

Can `<` or `>` be used in prepared statements?
Example:

```
value = ?
```

is it possible to have

```
value? or value>? or value<?
```

if my variable  was:

```
$myVar = ">0"
```

how could I use that in a prepared statement

Apologies in advance if this is a question of moronic proportions but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere and I find prepared statements utterly confusing..

scenario:

```
$houseVar = ">0";

$sqlQuery = " SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE myHouseID=?
GROUP BY SteetName"

$stmt=$con->prepare($sqlQuery);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $houseVar);
$stmt->execute();
```

Ordinary query works fine but prepared statement does not

Comment: No, you can't bind operators as parameters in a prepared statement. You *can* inject the operators in SQL though (**make SURE that you have a white list with accepted operators!!!**)

Comment: Are you trying to use those as *operators* in the query?  Or as appended/prepended characters on the values?  If the former, your examples don't make a lot of sense.  If the latter, you can just edit the value before using it as a query parameter.

Comment: You cannot. Even if there is a way to do that, i would still suggest not to follow. Instead, change the variable name.

Comment: Sorry h2oooooo, I get the first bit and appreciate the lightening response. part 2 of your statement is passing over at altitude. How do I inject operators and whats this white list you mention. clarity and help would be warmly received if I could understand how I could pass  myVar = ">0" that would be amazing.

Comment: David - I see light in what you are saying.I beleive I am trying to append characters to the value. I'll update my question in an attempt to clarify

Comment: If you add `>` to your variable, it would become a string and hopefully be encapsulated with `'` characters. So, no that does not work!

Comment: All, thank you for your answers and clarity. I appreciate all you responses.

Comment: @user2938700 Like `$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ' . $operator . ' :param';`. Also note that if you use `@h2ooooooo` (an at sign before the username), I'll get notified and get back to you quicker.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks again for your reply. I'd appreciate a little more help if possible. As you can tell this is all very new to me and sadly I'm getting a little to old to be learning new things. I'm building dynamic queries and I think I'm in way over my head. Don't know if I can PM you but would apprecaite further exchange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not able to bind operators to prepared statements.

You can make an hybrid and generate the prepared statement string with the runtime operator (and make sure to only allow those 5/6 valid operators) and then bind the variables normally.